# Simon game javascript, how do I synchronize the lights of the buttons not to step on each other with animation() and delay() JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, settimeout

I'm doing a Simon game and I'm taking the opacity from 1 to 0.3 and back to 1 everytime a sequence has place. It's almost working but the case that gives problem is when in the sequence I have the same color in a row.  GREEN, GREEN, RED, BLUE for example displays just one green press and one red and one blue. It's a problem with the timing cause the logic works fine. Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){


 let simon={
      colors:["green","red","yellow","blue"],
      sequence:[],
      userSequence:[],
      strict:false,
      buttonSounds : {},
      init: function(){
        let objectContext=this;


        $("#start").on("click",function(){

           objectContext.setSounds();


            //executes for the first time
  objectContext.emptyAllSequences();
           //I generate the first of the sequence
      objectContext.generateAndAddRandomColor();
           //I display the sequence on the board
      objectContext.displaySequenceOnBoard();


           }); 

          $("#title").addClass('tada animated');  

          $("#strict").on("click",function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("active");

            if($(this).hasClass("active")){
              objectContext.strict=true;
            }else{
              objectContext.strict=false;
            }

          });

       $(".button").on("click",function(){
            const color=$(this).attr("data-color");
           objectContext.lightButton(color,0);
            objectContext.userSequence.push(color);


            let isSequenceCorrect=objectContext.checkUserSequence();

       /*  console.log("sequenceCorrect "+isSequenceCorrect);
         console.log("sequence "+objectContext.sequence);
         console.log("user sequence "+objectContext.userSequence);
         console.log("user sec length "+objectContext.userSequence.length);
         console.log("sec length "+objectContext.sequence.length);*/
            if(objectContext.userSequence.length===objectContext.sequence.length || !isSequenceCorrect){

                if(isSequenceCorrect){
         setTimeout(function(){objectContext.generateAndAddRandomColor();
                  objectContext.displaySequenceOnBoard();
                  //reset the userSequence to check the whole sequence again 
                  objectContext.emptyUserSequence(); }, 1500);               
                }else{

                  //if strict mode is on
                  if(strict){
                    //user looses
                  $("#count").html("Lost");
                  //wipe sequence array
                   objectContext.emptyAllSequences();
                  $("#start").removeClass("active");
                  }else{

                    setTimeout(function(){
               //change this to generate another sequence instead of displaying the existent       
                  objectContext.displaySequenceOnBoard();
                  //reset the userSequence to check the whole sequence again 
                  objectContext.emptyUserSequence(); }, 1500);        



                  }
                }
            }
     });

  },
      setSounds:function(){

        this.buttonSounds["green"] = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3");
        this.buttonSounds["red"] = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3");
        this.buttonSounds["yellow"] = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3");
        this.buttonSounds["blue"] = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3");

      },

      emptyUserSequence: function(){
            this.userSequence.length=0;
      },

      emptyAISequence: function(){
               this.sequence.length=0;
      },

      emptyAllSequences:function(){
        this.emptyUserSequence();
        this.emptyAISequence();
      },
      updateCount: function(){
        $("#count").html(this.sequence.length);

      },

      checkUserSequence:function(){

        for(let i=0,len=this.userSequence.length;i<len;i++){

          if(this.userSequence[i]!== this.sequence[i]){
            return false;
          }

        }


        return true;    
      },

      generateAndAddRandomColor:function(){

        const randColorIndex=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);


        const randColor=this.colors[randColorIndex];
        this.sequence.push(randColor);
        this.updateCount(); 

      },

      displaySequenceOnBoard: function(){

        for(let i=0,len=this.sequence.length;i<len;i++){

          // this.buttonSounds[this.sequence[i]].play();
           this.lightButton(this.sequence[i],i);


        }//end for
      },
      lightButton: function(color,i){

        var objectContext=this;

                     $("#"+color).delay(400*i) 
        .animate({opacity : 0.3}, 300,function(){

                objectContext.buttonSounds[color].play();
                  $("#"+color).animate({opacity : 1}, 150);


                });


      }
    }
 simon.init();
});
```

Here's the codepen. You have to press start to start the game and as the sequence grows and is displayed on the board the problem commented before arises, what could be happening?. Thanks!

http://codepen.io/juanf03/pen/jrEdWz?editors=1111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting multiple delays on the same element at once, and the newest one just replaces the existing one.

Instead of using delays, pass a `complete` function with your animation, and give it the whole remaining sequence. To illustrate, replace your current `displaySequenceOnBoard()` with these two functions:

```
  displaySequenceOnBoard: function(){
    $(".button").removeClass("enabled");
    this.lightButtonsInSequence(this.sequence);

  },

  lightButtonsInSequence: function(sequence) {
    var color = sequence[0]
    var remainingSequence = sequence.slice(1)
    var lightNextButtonFunction = remainingSequence.length > 0 ? jQuery.proxy(function(){
                this.lightButtonsInSequence(sequence.slice(1));
              }, this) : null;
    console.log("Lighting color: " + color);
    $("#"+color).animate({opacity : .3}, 300).animate({opacity : 1}, 150, lightNextButtonFunction)

  }
```

Here it is plugged into your CodePen and [working](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozXNaE).

Comment: great answer, but could you explain me why I'm "setting multiple delays on the same element at once"?...I don't understand why....

Comment: @Juan Each time lightButton() is called, it sets a $().delay() on the element with the named color. The first time you call lightButton("green") it sets a delay on `#green`. Then the second time you call it (next iteration in the for loop) it sets another, longer delay on `#green`. But since an element can only have one delay, the second one replaces the first one.

Comment: clear as water...thank you very much....my final codepen is this

http://codepen.io/juanf03/pen/jrEdWz?editors=0001

it's working perfectly, the sounds were not working but I added it to your function. now I have a problem, when the same colors are in a row the 2nd sound doesn't sound......for example red red  only the first red sounds.....what could be happening? I added the sound on line 160

Comment: I already solved it by lowering the time. The files are from amazon s3 so if you set the timeout very low it doesn't sound the second time...Thank you again!! works perfectly!